# can someone guess the Database Schema of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, database-design, database-schema

I'm really interested to know how actually would be the database schema of Facebook? How many databases, tables and fields would be maintained? How is the updating done?

Comment: Voted to close...too general. In general, SO is not the place for case studies; if you have a specific question about schema design, spell out what you're looking for.

Comment: I think I have the UML somewhere...

Comment: One question mark is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, [here's a podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4746.html) from ITconversations describing Facebooks LAMP-stack. They seem to go with KISS as far as database schema goes.